# stop canvas shape from following cursor after a mouse click

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am making a GUI to draw weighted graphs using Tkinter, so I made a button that when clicked creates a circle(graph vertex) using canvas. then the circle should follow the cursor to any position on the canvas and stop when the mouse clicks.

I managed to make the the circle follow the cursor, but I have no idea how to make it stop following.

this is the function I made

```
def buttonClick():
    def Mouse_move(event):
        x,y = event.x , event.y
        canvas.moveto(vertex,x,y )

    vertex= canvas.create_oval(650, 100, 750, 200)
    canvas.bind("<Motion>", Mouse_move)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the mouse click event `<Button-1>` and unbind the `<Motion>` event in the callback:

```py
def buttonClick():
    def mouse_move(event):
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        canvas.moveto(vertex, x, y)

    def mouse_click(event):
        canvas.unbind("<Motion>")

    vertex = canvas.create_oval(650, 100, 750, 200)
    canvas.bind("<Motion>", mouse_move)
    canvas.bind("<Button-1>", mouse_click)
```